# C++ display map that has vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, std-pair

`std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> data;`

In order to print out this by using `copy`, how should my `std::ostream_iterator` be?

Apparently `std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> out_it(std::cout, "\n");` did not make it.

My `operator<<` overload is the following `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>& p)` and it writes out the `p.first` and `p.second` and returns it.

Comment: Figure out A) how to "display" a simple vector. B) how to display a simple map, e.g. `map<string, int>`. Then combine the two pieces of knowledge.

Comment: please give a complete code samples of what your whole operator<< looks like, how you want to use it in your code and how is the map filled.

Comment: @juanchopanza You mean that I will need to use a for-loop? Because to display a map it's `std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<std::string, int>> ...`

Comment: Your overloaded `operator<<` is unlikely to be used by `std::ostream_iterator`

Comment: @MarošBeťko Ok, my operator<< is just `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>& p)
{
    out << p.first << " ... " << p.second;
    return out ;
}`

Comment: @MarošBeťko I'm trying to print out the content of the map. The map is filled with string and vector of string.

Comment: @StoryTeller So I shouldn't put a vector into a pair? Doesn't seem to work when I try putting `pair<std::string, std::string>` neither. :/

Comment: You can put anything you want into the map if it makes sense in your program, why not.

Comment: @MarošBeťko Yes, but the real problem is when I try to display it. I'm not sure how to display a map where one of the input is a vector. If you or anyone could link an example snippet, would be great!

Comment: You can represent your data anyway you want. But pretty printing it may require an extra step. You can see my answer for one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a `operator<<` that will print out the contents of one pair from your map:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>& p) {
    out << p.first << ": "; // prints the string from key
    for (const auto& i : p.second) // loops throught the whole vector that is asociated with that key
        out << i << ", ";
    return out;
}
```

So to use it in this example. If you ennter this into your map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> data;
std::vector<std::string> vec = {"VAL1", "VAL2", "VAL3"};
data.insert(std::make_pair("KEY", vec));
auto it = data.find("KEY");
std::cout << *it;
```

This would be what wil get printed out using the operator<< above:

```
KEY: VAL1, VAL2, VAL3,
```

You can also change the formatting a bit so the comma isn't after the last value as well but that's only a cosmetic problem. Your problem was in that you wanted to print vector while it doesn't have std operator<<. So in order to print vector you must manually loop through it's content like in my example with the ranged for.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was the most clear for me at my level. It was easy for me to understand and relevant to my exercise. Your `operator<<` works perfectly for my case, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you do any serious programming in C++, you will eventually need a generic way to print out collections.

Here is the basis of one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


// introduce the concept of an object that emits values to an ostream
// by default it simply calls operator <<
template<class T> struct emitter
{
    using arg_type = T;

    emitter(const T& v) : v_(v) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const emitter& e) {
        return os << e.v_;
    }

    const T& v_;
};

// introduce the concept of an io manipulator called emit
template<class T> auto emit(const T& v) -> emitter<T>
{
    return emitter<std::decay_t<T>>(v);
}

// specialise the emitter for maps
template<class K, class V, class C, class A>
struct emitter<std::map<K, V, C, A>>
{
    using arg_type = std::map<K, V, C, A>;

    emitter(const arg_type& v) : v_(v) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const emitter& e) {
        const char* elem_sep = "\n\t";
        const char* end_sep = " ";
        os << "{";
        for (const auto& elem : e.v_)
        {
            os << elem_sep << emit(elem.first) << ": " << emit(elem.second);
            end_sep = "\n";
        }

        return os << end_sep << "}";
    }

    const arg_type& v_;
};

// specialise the emitter for vectors
template<class V, class A>
struct emitter<std::vector<V, A>>
{
    using arg_type = std::vector<V, A>;

    emitter(const arg_type& v) : v_(v) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const emitter& e) {
        const char* elem_sep = " ";
        const char* end_sep = " ";
        os << "[";
        for (const auto& elem : e.v_)
        {
            os << elem_sep << emit(elem);
            elem_sep = ", ";
        }

        return os << end_sep << "]";
    }

    const arg_type& v_;
};


int main() {
    // build test data
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> data;

    data.emplace("a", std::vector<std::string>{ "now", "is", "the", "time" });
    data.emplace("b", std::vector<std::string>{ "for", "all", "good", "men" });
    data.emplace("c", std::vector<std::string>{ "to", "come", "to", "the" });
    data.emplace("d", std::vector<std::string>{ "aid", "of", "their", "party" });

    // request an emitter manipulator
    std::cout << emit(data) << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    a: [ now, is, the, time ]
    b: [ for, all, good, men ]
    c: [ to, come, to, the ]
    d: [ aid, of, their, party ]
}
```

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. Although I think it's on a bit higher level than the author's question.

Comment: @MarošBeťko I don't think c++ is a level-based game. As the old saying goes, "you can't get a little bit pregnant" ;-)

Comment: @RichardHodges Thank you for the great input. I'm still at the newb level, it's just not something I've encountered in my course yet, but I'm sure it will make a good use in the future! Thank you, again!

Comment: @user3221454 It'll do you good to see if you can make sense of it. Never hurts to be ahead of the curve. Best of luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

To custom print your vector, you'd have to write some code yourself. To make sure your custom operator is used, I suggest you use `std::stringstream` to turn your key-value pair into a string, which you'd then feed into an `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>`.

Something, like [this](http://ideone.com/ppNQzE) (pardon the `using namespace std;`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, vector<string>> m {
        {"a", {"1", "2"}},
        {"b", {"1", "2"}},
        {"b", {"1", "2"}},
    };

    transform(begin(m), end(m), ostream_iterator<string>(cout), [](auto& p){
        stringstream ss;
        ss << p.first << ", {";
        bool first = true;
        for (auto& s : p.second)
        {
          ss << (first ? "" : ", ") << s;
          first = false;
        }
        ss << "}\n";
        return ss.str();
    });

    return 0;
}
```

I didn't actually write the `operator<<`, but you can substitue yours to make the lambda body short);