# How do I simply print a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a vector like this:

```
struct vector3D {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

vector3D aVector = { 3.4, 4.4, 9.3 }; // my vector
```

How can I `cout` the `aVector` to the console?

Comment: You can either print each member of the struct (cout << aVector.x << " " << aVector.y << " " << aVector.z;) or overload << operator for cout.

Comment: I literally don't know why I asked this question, I just figured this out before looking at your reply. It's cool, I understand the down votes :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41097964/2015579

Comment: By writing code to perform that function

Answer (score 5):

you can overload the insertion operator `<<` to use for your objects:

```
struct vector3D {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, vector3D rhs){
            out << "( " << rhs.x << ", " << rhs.y << ", " << rhs.z << " )" << endl;
            return out; 
    }
};
```

now you can use `cout` to print your object values:

```
int main(){
    vector3D v = {10, 20, 30};
    cout << v << endl;
}
```